# Reducing repeated code in Flask and Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using Flask-SQLAlchemy and I have a database with various tables and relations. I want the user to be able to create an entry in a table like (category) edit an entry in a table and view all entries in that table.

So I have two classes Category and Revision. Category just has a name and Revision has a name and a version.

my code to add and edit are:

### Category

```
def addCategory(name):
    cat = models.Category(name=name)
    db.session.add(cat)
    try:
        db.session.commit()
    except sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError:
        print "adding a row that violates the unique constraint"
```

### Revision

```
def addRevision(name, version):
    cat = models.Revision(name=name, version=version)
    db.session.add(cat)

    try:
        db.session.commit()
    except sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError:
        print "adding a row that violates the unique constraint"
```

### Category

```
def editCategory(name, newName):
    cat = models.Category.query.filter_by(name=name).first()
    if cat:
        cat.name = newName
        db.session.add(cat)
        try:
            db.session.commit()
            return True
        except sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError:
            print "That Category already exists"
    return False
```

### Revision

```
def editRevision(name, version, newName, newVersion):
    rev = models.Revision.query.filter_by(name=name, version=version).first()
    if rev:
        rev.name = newName
        rev.version = newVersion
        db.session.add(rev)
        try:
            db.session.commit()
            return True
        except sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError:
            print "That Revision already exists"
    return False
```

The same goes for my templates. Viewing all categories is very similar to viewing all revisions. Adding a revision is similar to adding a category. etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pluggable views](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/views/#pluggable-views) should help you reduce your replicated code.